# Let $F$ be an infinite field. Then is it true that there does not exist any surjection from $F$ onto $F[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, cardinals

Let $F$ be an infinite field. Then is it true that $|F|<|F[x]|$, i.e., is it true that there does not exist any surjection from $F$ onto $F[x]$, i.e., there does not exist any injection from $F[x]$ into $F$ ?

Comment: This is false. Both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are countable sets.

Comment: More can be said. $F$ and $F[x]$ always have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 3):

There certainly exists a surjection from $F$ onto $F[x]$. It seems likely that there is no surjective *homomorphism*...

In what sense? Well, for example, $F$ and $F[x]$ are both $F$-vector spaces; since $\dim(F)<\dim(F[x])$ there is no $F$-linear surjection.

Comment: +1. Note for the OP: however, if $E$ is a subfield of $F$ there might well be a surjective homomorphism of $E$-vector spaces $F\rightarrow F[x]$ - specifically, if $F$ has infinite transcendence degree over $E$.

Answer (score 3):

There can even be algebraically nice maps between the two rings in the counterintuitive direction.

For example, let $F = \Bbb Q(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ be the field of rational functions in infinitely many variables over the rational numbers. Then there is an injective ring homomorphism $\Phi\colon F[x]\to F$, determined by $\Phi(x) = x_1$ and $\Phi(x_j) = x_{j+1}$ for $j\ge1$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is wrong. Assume the field $F$ contains countably infinitely many elements. Then the polynomial ring $F[x]\simeq\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}F\cdot x^i$ as an $F$-module. We know the countably infinite union of countably infinite sets is again countably infinite, then $|F[x]|=|F|$, i.e., there exists a surjection from $F$ to $F[x]$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: More generally: as long as $F$ is infinite, $F$ and $F[x]$ have the same cardinality. (Assuming the axiom of choice.)

Comment: Sure, I agree with you. This is because of the isomorphism I wrote in my answer.